# Given facebook username, password, and application's ID can a web application acquire user id and access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-access-token

I'm developing a web application using PHP. This PHP will contain a function which accepts  facebook username, password, and application's ID, and return (or write) user's ID and access token (preferably as JSON format)

The problematic thing is that, as much as I know, Facebook API for authentication requires the user to manually click some kind of 'OK' buttons through Facebook's pop-up interface. I don't want this behavior as this web application will be used by application in another platform (non-PHP, well in this case it will be Unity3D).

Comment: So, you're trying to avoid having the user explicitly authorize your app?

Comment: So, you're trying to steal people's usernames and passwords?

Comment: No, it's just that Unity3D (as far as I know) doesn't have the mean to do communication with web-browser. It can only communicate by passing parameters, and then returning a JSONObject.

Comment: Here is an example of how to do it in Python, you could do it in a similar manner: http://ruel.me/blog/2011/03/03/scrape-your-facebook-friends-emails-with-python/

Answer (score 3):

Prompting the user for their username and password is bad practice, because it gives you unlimited access to their accounts, which in general users will be hesitant to do. Instead, you could do the device authentication:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/

Comment: Cool, I'm gonna try it later. Thanks! :D

Edit: wait, if I'm not mistaken, this means that there is no way the app can know which facebook entity is the user, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but if you call graph.facebook.com/me, you'll get info about the user that the the auth_token belongs to.